# How can I run a script that open terminal and execute .sh file from Website

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I wish to run these code from one click event in website though a button. I using PHP to execute the shell script. Inside the shell script I have those coding, and I realize that this line of code wont work. How can I open a terminal remotely using a website ?(Currently I am using PHP)

```
lxterminal -e -hold
```

Seeking For expert like you to help ! Thanks ^^

Comment: check about `shell_exec()` or `exec()` function

Comment: that one I done ~ It can execute the shell script . The problem is it cannot open the terminal

Comment: What do you mean by open terminal... do you want to pop it out.. oh no you can't do that

Comment: what the reason I cant do that ?... Bcoz I need to run some command to the terminal ... example Is it possible I run a command -ls using onclick button at webpage remotely?

Comment: Yah again you have to use ajax to pass the onclick event to php and in php you have to `shell_exec` or `exec` ...

Comment: The idea is, I have a webpage and inside it got one button [ Run The Machine ]. I can run the machine locally using LXterminal and key in the command, now I wish to run the machine remotely, so I need to have a script that can open the terminal and run the command ? Or perhaps another way to do ?

Comment: Using AJAX, Run shell script all I have done already, there no problem there, I tested and can echo back the content

Comment: No you can't just assume you open terminal on your website and i am one of the user i run a command `rm -rf /` you know what it does

Comment: yup ... It is dangerous ... But the script only I know and I believe no body gonna to hack it bcoz it run at local server

Comment: If I persist in to do that... Please suggest a method to do ... I really need it to run the machine remotely ...